# Getting error when trying to get data from one table to another

Tags: laravel

When I try to get something from Posts to User, it Works. Getting something from User to Post, it does not work

Here is the error I get

```
Trying to get property of non-object 
(View: /var/www/html/laravel/app/views/post/listing.blade.php)
```

Here is what I did
http://laravel.io/bin/yGoMm

Answer (score 0):

Users has many posts, when you try to access `user -> post` you will get an error, because you are trying a collection of objects.
So you will need to loop through `user -> posts as post` to access each user's posts

```
$users = 
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"joe",
  "posts: 
    [
     {"id":1,"title":"post 1"},
     {"id":2,"title":"post 2"}
    ]
}
foreach ($users -> posts as $post)
{
   echo $post -> title; 
}
```

Hope this help.